# Regex for searching website in string/webPageString

Tags: asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

I want Regex for searching one Website from string/webpage

```
<li class="website">
<h4>Website</h4>
<p>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2EBankerBay%2Ecom&amp;urlhash=z2FT&amp;trk=BankerBay_website" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://www.yahoo.com</a>
</p>
</li>
```

I want to search this website from this code/webPageCode ( http://www.yahoo.com)
 always website will be different but this will come in this html format

Thanks in advance

Comment: I try this 
Regex objRegex = new Regex("<li class=\"website\">.*>(.+)</a>.*</li>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
but not working

Comment: this is working fine ( @"((http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)" ) but this is giving more then 300 result in whole webpage string so i want only one which is in this html tag .... any one can answer me please